# How to add spinner to select list using ajax programmatically?

Tags: ajax, drupal-8

I want to add spinner to select list using ajax. I have tried below code for throbber but it's not working for select list.

```
$form['select choice'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Choice'),
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => ['js-dop-chosen'],
  ],
  '#options' => [
    '---' => t('None'),
    t('choice 1'),
    t('choice 2'),
  ],
  '#ajax' => [
    'event' => 'change',
    'wrapper' => 'form-wrapper',
    'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxCallback'],
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => 'fetching content.....',
    ],
  ],
];
```

Comment: Does it work without the 'js-dop-chosen' class? Maybe that is interfereing with the default throbber?

Comment: It's not working if I remove 'js-dop-chosen' class.

Comment: There is not enough information in your post to help any further, your array structure looks ok from what I remember.... Maybe chack the browser console for arrors.